# Get JavaSparkContext from a SparkSession

Tags: java, apache-spark

Im am using a `SparkSession` to run my spark application because I use a lot of spark-sql features. I would like to use the `JavaSparkContext`to create an RDD from a list. But via the Session I can only get an *ordinary* `SparkContext`. Is there a way to transform the context in this direction?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After determining the `SparkContext`, you could use:

```
SparkContext sc = ...
JavaSparkContext jsc = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(sc);
```

This will return you the new instance of `JavaSparkContext`, but there is no problem as long as you maintain just one active instance of the `SparkContext`.

Answer (score 16):

Yep, you can do that with the spark session like this:

```
   val spark = SparkSession.builder()
         .config(sparkConf)
         .getOrCreate()

    val jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext)
```

or in java, it would be:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate();
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
```

Comment: note for those that use sonar: S2095 want that we close the JavaSparkContext when created using new. Just use `JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(sc)` instead